# Why does this say permission denied?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, terminal

I created a react app and it did not install all the packages. So I did
`which create-react-app` command on my terminal and it returned me `/usr/local/bin/create-react-app` so I ran `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app` command but it returned me with permission denied. What should I do to not to allow it?

Comment: **sudo m -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run command as a super user

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app`